# I'm looking for a text editor that I can access from a browser on a different server

Tags: remote, editors, browser

Much like you can do with Jupyter Notebook. I can start a jupyter server on a linux box and access that on a different computer. I know I can use Jupyter as a text editor, but it is very light-weight. Are there any text editors that I can also access from a browser?

EDIT: The main thing I'm looking for is the nested directory structure and to easily switch between files without opening a new tab.

Comment: If you are happy `ssh` and the command line you might consider `tmux` (which gives you a shared terminal windows that you can access over `ssh`) or `emacsclient` which allows you to remotely access an emacs.  This does require that you have `ssh` on the client machine, which I'm guessing is one of your motivations. You might be able to combine this with something like [tty.js](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/) to give you access from a machine without a browser.

Comment: I never knew about `tmux`. Thanks! It may be the best option unfortunately.

Comment: So I had a play with this `tty.js` and can confirm that it works with `emacs`, `emacsclient` and `tmux` (well I didn't hit up against any problems with 5 minutes of poking).  So if you want to be able to access your server from arbitrary machines (e.g. you are at a party and your server stops working!) then this might be the way to go. I would not that using `emacsclient` lets you connect to your gui emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup and problem. I've just started using [sshcode](https://github.com/cdr/sshcode/) which allows you to "Run VS Code on any server over SSH" and seems to fit the bill. It runs VS Code on the remote server and gives you a full IDE in Chrome on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to type this into your browser's address bar:

```
data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```

and it will become a notebook